# Arduino Multiple SPI issue

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, wifi, spi

I am literally on the last part of my project and it is to take control of a POT using a digital pot. I have a MCP4131 digital pot, however I can't seem to get it to work. I figured it is due to the wifly shield I have connected, as it uses the SPI as well. I have an arduino mega connected to a WIFFLY shield, I also have a bluetooth module connected and a TFT connected to another arduino. The bluetooth module and the tft screen just send data to the serial (2 and 3) so I know it isn't the issue. I will post my code below if anyone can help me solve this last bit I will be so greatful.

```
 #include <SPI.h>
#include <WiFly.h>
#include <Wire.h>


WiFlyServer server(2000);

byte address = 0x11;

int CS= 10;


int led = 47;

String readString;
String readString2;
char c;
int i;
char d;


int photocellReading;



int number_4 = 255;
int number_5 = 111;
int number_6 = 93;
int number_7 = 75;
int number_8 = 56;
int number_9 = 38;
int number_10 = 18;
int number_11 = 0;

int pwmpin = 9; 


void setup() {
    WiFly.begin();
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial3.begin(9600);
    Serial2.begin(9600);
      server.begin();
      pinMode (CS, OUTPUT);
     SPI.begin();
       pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
        pinMode(pwmpin, OUTPUT);



}

void loop() {

//resetFunc();
WiFlyClient client = server.available();

if(Serial2.available()){ 
while(Serial2.available() > 0) {
    char d = Serial2.read();  //gets one byte from serial buffer
    readString2 += d; //makes the string readString
    delay(5);  //slow looping to allow buffer to fill with next character

}


if (readString2.length() >0){

   int commaIndex2 = readString2.indexOf(',');
   int secondCommaIndex2 = readString2.indexOf(',', commaIndex2+1);

String firstValue2 = readString2.substring(0, commaIndex2);
String secondValue2 = readString2.substring(commaIndex2+1, secondCommaIndex2);
String thirdValue2 = readString2.substring(secondCommaIndex2+1); // To the end of the string

int x2 = firstValue2.toInt();
int y2 = secondValue2.toInt();
int z2 = thirdValue2.toInt();
if(x2 == 200){
if(y2 == 4){
digitalWrite(led, LOW);

}
}
}
//empty for next input

}



if (client.connect()){


      while (client.available()) {

        c = client.read();
        readString += c; //makes the string readString
    delay(5);  //slow looping to allow buffer to fill with next character

      }

if (readString.length() >0){

   int commaIndex = readString.indexOf(',');
   int secondCommaIndex = readString.indexOf(',', commaIndex+1);

String firstValue = readString.substring(0, commaIndex);
String secondValue = readString.substring(commaIndex+1, secondCommaIndex);
String thirdValue = readString.substring(secondCommaIndex+1); // To the end of the string

int x = firstValue.toInt();
int y = secondValue.toInt();
int z = thirdValue.toInt();

Serial.println(x);

if(x == 4){

digitalWrite(led, HIGH);

digitalWrite(CS, LOW);
SPI.transfer(address);
SPI.transfer(number_4);
digitalWrite(CS, HIGH);


  }

}

}
if (!client.connected() || !server.available()){

  while(SpiSerial.available() > 0) {

#if ARDUINO >= 100
    Serial3.write(SpiSerial.read());
#else
    Serial3.print(SpiSerial.read(), BYTE);
#endif
delay(100);
  }

  if(Serial3.available()) { // Outgoing data
#if ARDUINO >= 100  
    SpiSerial.write(Serial3.read());
#else
    SpiSerial.print(Serial3.read(), BYTE);
#endif

  }

}



readString=""; //empty for next input
readString2=""; 


 }
```

As you can see the bluetooth and the tft screen are just to send data and my only issue is this. As stated before if anyone can help me get the pot to read I will be so grateful.